# Delete button - change state with handleClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to write the code for my handleClick() function in my CARD.js file.
I am trying to delete the card when the delete button gets clicked. I am struggling with this because the state that needs to be changed is in my HOME file and not in the CARD file where my handleclick function is. What code should I use in my handleclick function (CARD file) to filter (=delete) the state in the HOME file? How do you do this linking or is it not possible?

---

**HOME.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import {movies} from "./movies.js"
import Card from "./Card.js"
import "./Home.css"

class Home extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            movieslist: movies   
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="homecontainer">
                {
                    this.state.movieslist.map(movie =>{
                       return <Card title={movie.title} category={movie.category} likes={movie.likes} dislikes={movie.dislikes} />
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

---

**CARD.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import "./Card.css"

class Card extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            active:false
        }

        this.toggleClass=this.toggleClass.bind(this)
    }

    toggleClass(){
        const currentState = this.state.active;
        this.setState({ active: !currentState });
    }

    handleClick(){
        // How do I link this with the state in the HOME file
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="cardbox">
                    <div className="cardtitle">{this.props.title}</div>
                    <div>{this.props.category}</div>
                    <div>{this.props.likes / this.props.dislikes}</div>
                    <i onClick={this.toggleClass} className={this.state.active?"fa fa-thumbs-up":"fa fa-thumbs-down"}></i>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Delete</button>
                </div>    
        )
    }
}

export default Card
```

Answer (score 0):

React has one way data flow, so you need to write a function in your home component that changes the state, and then pass the function down to the card.js component.

Comment: could you please elaborate on this/write it out in full detail? Would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Sure, sorry I didn't go in to more detail. 
So in your home component you need to write a function that changes the state. And then pass this function down to the card component, calling it there. 
I see 0stone0 did the code for you.